# Is it possible to use multiple bluetooth profiles for a pair of devices?

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, bluetooth

I have a project in mind that uses Bluetooth and I'm currently doing some research. What I have in mind is to build an app that can send audio signal via bluetooth to a raspberry pi 3 and be able to control the GPIO pins of the raspberry pi all in the same app. This means I'll be using some sort of audio profile and a serial profile (for the GPIO portion).

However, I'm not entirely sure if this is possible because I'm essentially running two different profiles between paired devices. Is this possible? Or does it depend on some other factor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy one...yes, it's possible to run multiple profiles on the same pair.  I've personally run HFP and SPP simultaneously.